# How to avoid extra wrapping <div> in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today I have started learning ReactJS and after an hour faced with the problem..
I want to insert a component which has two rows inside a div on the page.A simplified example of what I am doing below.

I have an html:

```
<html>
..
  <div id="component-placeholder"></div>
..
</html>
```

Render function like this:

```
...
render: function() {

    return(
        <div className="DeadSimpleComponent">
            <div className="DeadSimpleComponent__time">10:23:12</div >
            <div className="DeadSimpleComponent__date">MONDAY, 2 MARCH 2015</div>
        </div>
    )
}
....
```

And below I am calling render:

```
ReactDOM.render(<DeadSimpleComponent/>, document.getElementById('component-placeholder'));
```

Generated HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
..
  <div id="component-placeholder">
    <div class="DeadSimpleComponent">
            <div class="DeadSimpleComponent__time">10:23:12</div>
            <div class="DeadSimpleComponent__date">MONDAY, 2 MARCH 2015</div>
    </div>
</div>
..
</html>
```

The problem that I am not a very happy that React forcing me to wrap all in a div "DeadSimpleComponent". What is the best and simple workaround for it, without explicit DOM manipulations?

**UPDATE 7/28/2017: Maintainers of React added that possibility in React 16 Beta 1**

Since [React 16.2](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html), you can do this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: perfect naming practice ;-)

Comment: Could I see your HTML file? I mis-read your question. I may have a workaround though.

Comment: Smth like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qawumm3v/

Comment: You have a problem with a component having a single element? Really?

Comment: What do you mean? I am just trying React, it should not be very complicated.. But limitation looks annoying.

Comment: Kiril, How? Please update your answer with the solution.

Comment: + for `<> ... </>`

Answer (score 189, accepted):

This requirement was removed in React version (16.0), so now you are able to avoid that wrapper.

You can use React.Fragment to render a list of elements without creating a parent node, official example:

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

More here: [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Comment: Great news DmitryUlyanets. Is there any planned release date?

Comment: It is released since September 26, 2017, see https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html

Comment: You can also use the shorthand: <> </> instead of <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>

Answer (score 74):

**Update 2017-12-05:** 
[React v16.2.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html) now fully supports rendering of fragments with improved support for returning multiple children from a components render method without specifying keys in children:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </>
  );
}
```

If you are using a React version prior to v16.2.0, it is also possible to use `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>` instead:

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

---

**Original:**

React v16.0 introduced returning an array of elements in render method without wrapping it in a div: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html

```
render() {
  // No need to wrap list items in an extra element!
  return [
    // Don't forget the keys :)
    <li key="A">First item</li>,
    <li key="B">Second item</li>,
    <li key="C">Third item</li>,
  ];
}
```

At the moment, a key is required for each element to avoid the key warning but this could be changed in future releases:

> In the future, we’ll likely add a special fragment syntax to JSX that
>   doesn’t require keys.

Comment: The new shorthand syntax of <></> is great. I still have a lot of mixed feeling about it however.

Comment: @ThulaniChivandikwa Would you mind to voice your misgivings about the shorthand syntax?

Comment: I think it is more about the concept of an empty tag being odd in the JSX and not very intuitive unless you know exactly what it does.

Comment: I was a bit confused by the comment "add a special fragment syntax to JSX that doesn’t require keys". They meant that once they introduced fragments, you wouldn't need a key on each list element like you used to. You still need `<Fragment key={foo}>` when you use them in a list.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
render(){
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
           <div>Some data</div>
           <div>Som other data</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

For further details refer to [this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Answer (score 5):

Use [], instead of ()'s to wrap the entire return.

```
render: function() {
  return[
    <div className="DeadSimpleComponent__time">10:23:12</div >
    <div className="DeadSimpleComponent__date">MONDAY, 2 MARCH 2015</div>
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a component to wrap child components without a DIV. It's called a shadow wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-shadow-wrapper

Comment: I posted an issue on your package, can you please have a look? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**This is still required**, ***BUT*** *React now make sure to create elements without creating an additional DOM element.*

The extra wrapping needed (normally with a parent `div`) because Reacts `createElement` method require a `type` parameter which is `either a tag name string (such as 'div' or 'span'), a React component type (a class or a function)`. But this was before they introduce React `Fragment`.

Refer [this NEW api doc for createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

> **React.createElement** : Create and return a new React element of the given type. The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as 'div' or 'span'), a React component type (a class or a function), **or a React fragment type**.

here is the official example, Refer [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment).

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      Some text.
      <h2>A heading</h2>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been answered, you can of course use React.Fragment which doesn't create a node but let's you group stuff like a div.

Additionally if you want to have fun you can implement (and learn lots of things) a React mode that removes the extra div's and for this I really want to share a great video on how you can do it on the react code base itself.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aS41Y_eyNrU

This is of course not something that you would do in practice but it's a good learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get rid of that `div` element. React.render() needs to return one valid DOM node.

Comment: the div's are ignored, Knockout.JS does the same thing.  having a div with no styling on the outer part of your component effects nothing.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes, disagree. one wrapper div affects the css selectors.

Comment: When working with semantic elements, that you don't want to be entirely React components, this become an issue. Lets say there's an section-tag with header and footer elements, and between them there is a google map-container, that we don't want to use within React. Then there would be nice to have header as a React component and Footer as a React component, without having to include extra div:s outside on inside the React components... That is plain stupid design, if you care at all about the html you output...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to render "transculent" components:

```
import React from 'react'

const Show = (props) => {
  if (props.if || false) {
    return (<React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>)
  }
  return '';
};

----


<Show if={yomama.so.biq}>
    <img src="https://yomama.so.biq">
    <h3>Yoamama</h3>
<Show>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is workaround too. The below block code generates fragment without the need of React.Fragment.

```
return [1,2,3].map(i=>{
if(i===1) return <div key={i}>First item</div>
if(i===2) return <div key={i}>Second item</div>
return <div key={i}>Third item</div>
})
```