# React: placeholder (neutral) element for text in JSX

Tags: reactjs, text, jsx, placeholder

I have a React component that has few links in `<a>` separated by comma `,`.

```
<a href={'https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?ty=c&ta=0&p=w&t=' + stock.ticker}>FinViz</a>,
<a href={'https://www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=fin&q=' + stock.ticker}>Google Finance</a>,
...
```

When rendered, the comma at the end turns into `<span>,</span>`.

How can I prevent this? I need the text to be free of extra elements (for CSS styling purposes).

I saw recently that React has some pseudo-element, like `<react:something>,</...>` which are not rendered. But can't find it.

Alternatively, is it possible to turn of generating of the span tags?

Comment: I found it... there's already that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766085/how-to-avoid-extra-wrapping-div-in-react

Comment: I am not sure whether it's a duplicate or not. That question has different motivation, but perhaps the same solution.