# React renders pointless div breaking my flexbox style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm familiar with React Native but not so much with ReactJS. I have a styling issue: I'm modifying this lib for a hobby project: https://github.com/rcdexta/react-trello and the code I'm interested in looks like this:

```
// Render Method
return (
    <BoardDiv style={style} {...otherProps} draggable={false}>
      <UpdateModal
        isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
        onClick={this.closeModal.bind(this)}
        card={this.state.card}
        onRequestClose={this.closeModal}/>
      <PopoverWrapper>
        <Container
          orientation="horizontal"
          onDragStart={this.onDragStart}
          dragClass={laneDragClass}
          dropClass=""
          onDrop={this.onLaneDrop}
          lockAxis="x"
          getChildPayload={index => this.getLaneDetails(index)}
          groupName={this.groupName}>
          {reducerData.lanes.map((lane, index) => {
            const {id, droppable, ...otherProps} = lane
            const laneToRender = (
              <Lane
                key={id}
                boardId={this.groupName}
                id={id}
                getCardDetails={this.getCardDetails}
                onCardClick={(cardId, metadata, laneId) => {
                  const allCards = [].concat(...this.props.reducerData.lanes.map((lane) => lane.cards))
                  const cardData = allCards.filter((e) => e.id === cardId)[0]
                  this.modifyCardTitle(cardData)
                }}
                index={index}
                droppable={droppable === undefined ? true : droppable}
                {...otherProps}
                {...passthroughProps}
              />
            )
            return draggable && laneDraggable ? <Draggable key={lane.id}>{laneToRender}</Draggable> :
              <span key={lane.id}>{laneToRender}</span>
          })}
        </Container>
      </PopoverWrapper>
      {canAddLanes && (
        <Container orientation="horizontal">
          {editable && !addLaneMode ? (
            <LaneSection style={{width: 200}}>
              <NewLaneButton onClick={this.showEditableLane}>{addLaneTitle}</NewLaneButton>
            </LaneSection>
          ) : (
            addLaneMode && this.renderNewLane()
          )}
        </Container>
      )}
    </BoardDiv>
)
```

However the rendering looks like this:

```
<div class="react-trello-board sc-bdVaJa eBPLjG" data="[object Object]" draggable="false">
  <div> <!--The problem-->
    <div class="smooth-dnd-container horizontal">
        <section title="will_apply" draggable="false" class="react-trello-board sc-htpNat dJewwL"
                 style="width: 25%;">
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is the following: I have no idea why React created the div marked as problem (see snippet above) and it breaks my "flexbox workflow" because `display: flex` is not propagating through it (it displays `block`).

What are my options?

Should I override and style all my `div`s with, let's say, `display: flex; flex:1`? Can I see where and why this `div` has been created?

Comment: possible guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766085/how-to-avoid-extra-wrapping-div-in-react

Comment: ReactJS doesn't create any containers by itself, unless it is told to, that `div` should be coming from the depths of one of those Components you make use of.

Comment: I suspect the component `Container` to be the culprit. Could you share the code of that component please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra `div` is coming from `PopoverWrapper`, [here](https://github.com/terebentina/react-popover/blob/e49a1d6be32b93eab32f6d73a5e3b7a74abf7e4a/src/Popover.jsx#L114).

The library gives 2 ways of styling, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/rcdexta/react-trello#styling). If that doesn't meet your needs, you'll need to change the code to pass classes or styles to the required DOM elements that you want to style.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like that to avoid to render unnecessary div:

```
<React.Fragment>
 <YourComponent />
 // ... Or the component content
</React.Fragment>
```