# Why does React need an enclosing tag to return multiple sibling elements?

Tags: reactjs

So while it is known that adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. I haven't been able to find the reason behind that. Why does React enforce that behavior ?

Comment: Because that is how HTML tags work in JSX? Or are you asking about why every component needs to return an array of nodes, or a single node element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag) and [How to avoid extra wrapping <div> in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766085)

Answer (score 2):

Because this:

```html
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
```

Will produce this:

```js
React.DOM.div(...)React.DOM.div(...)
```

Which doesn't make syntactical sense.

Also, you don't have to use an enclosing element, you can return an array instead, e.g:

```js
return [
    <div>...</div>,
    <div>...</div>
]
```

Just don't forget to add a unique `key` to each of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

From the [React Dev docs](https://react.dev/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx):

> JSX looks like HTML, but under the hood it is transformed into plain
> JavaScript objects. You can’t return two objects from a function
> without wrapping them into an array. This explains why you also can’t
> return two JSX tags without wrapping them into another tag or a
> Fragment.